# Facebook login callback not working when using Facebook app - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I had a perfectly functional application on the app store for over a year which featured Facebook signup and it all worked without any problems. However, few days ago I got few complaints from users who say that Facebook login causes the app to get stuck on login screen. I've investigated the behaviour and it seems that the callback from Facebook after clicking on login button does not work when you use Facebook app to authenticate. Going through Safari works. I've updated my Cocoapod libs to the latest version and in my AppDelegate I have the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions) 
    return true
}


func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

All my Plist files are in order, Facebook didn't suspend my app or anything similar, and again it works when I try to sign in using Safari. Version of iOS is 11 and i'm using Swift 3.

Comment: Have you given URL Schemes in URL Types in Info tab in your project target?

Comment: I do, the app worked before I didn't change anything regarding login code almost half a year.

Comment: Did you solve it? My app work fine with login via web, but cannot via Facebook app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've done a log in via Facebook and this may cause some problems
It is best to use the latest update for Facebook sdk using pod or download facebook framework latest version

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

see facebook  [LoginBehavior](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/blob/master/Sources/Login/LoginBehavior.swift)

based on last update for facebook sdk It should appear this way

[image]

And check plist info same this

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{your-app-id}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{your-app-name}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: It does appear, and when I click "Login With Facebook App" there is no callback to my app, just opens it and gets stuck on splash screen. However, if I click "Login with phone or email" then the auth process happens on Safari and it works.

Comment: You mean to use Facebook Login button instead of my custom flow? Hm, I can try that see what happens.

Comment: look here and check plist  keys 

https://iswift.org/playground?R99ZOC&v=3

Comment: Okay now I understood your question. I was using a bit different code with FBSDKLoginManager instead of LoginManager however, with the code you provided it's still the same thing. When using Facebook app the code gets stuck on splash screen. I've triple checked my Plist file it's identical to what you've sent me. I'm really running out of ideas here.

Comment: Ok , please give to me Facebook SDK version

Comment: It's the latest version
FBSDKCoreKit (4.31.1)
FBSDKLoginKit (4.31.1)
FBSDKMessengerShareKit (1.3.2)
FBSDKShareKit (4.31.1)
FacebookLogin (0.3.0)
FacebookShare (0.3.0)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, it was a mistake in the Info.plist file I was missing a <string>Editor</string> inside CFBundleTypeRole even though the Info.plist in your project example is not the same as they've put it on official website here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started 
They didn't put it here.

Comment: Can you add Plist info in your answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @NerminSehic I tried all the way also added your suggestion of Editor Role but I am still not able to make it work. Login by facebook button not working but if i do login via email or phone then it works fine so I am not getting what is the issue there? I have updated pods too. After Click on OPEN button it opens the app and back to the application but i don't get any response from facebook login methods so can you please help to get rid of this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Works For FBSDK version 5.0.0 and later

in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
}
```

after that, you can add

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        AppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

and then

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: (url as URL?)!, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

by following that, should works with you.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above by @a.masri,

Facebook Login SDK Documentation neglected to include this in the plist snippet. This fully resolved the crash for me. Thanks @a.masri

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>   ///ADD THIS
        <string>Editor</string>      ///AND THIS
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>flex</string>
            <string>fb323015428110219</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch any response from Facebook to get a better idea where your request it's being stopped. For example Facebook changes the policies for readPermissions from time to time (is not usual) but that may cause an error on your request.

I try to get a better idea when i make a request like this:

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.email, .publicProfile, .userFriends, .userBirthday], viewController: parentVC) { (result) in

            //Check the response
            switch result {

            case .failed(let error):

                #if DEBUG
                    print("Failed login: ", error.localizedDescription)
                #endif

                completionHandler(.connectionError)
                break

            case .cancelled:
                completionHandler(.cancelledError)

                break
            case .success(_, _, _):

                //We have success, make graph Request
                self.makeGraphRequest(completionHandler: completionHandler)

                break

            }//Check the pemrmissions response

        }// Ends loginManager.logIn
```

Comment: Tried that already, I can't catch the response since I don't get a response. The callback literally doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try FBSDKLoginButton and use the Delegate method of that. It will help you. If you want to login with your browser only and want to remove "Login with the Facebook App" then remove LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array of strings from your info.plist. It will remove the app login option.
```

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```